# How to get value of input field using documentid javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This function uses jQuery and javascript with HTML and doesn't work as intended.

Am using a daterange picker with predifed format using moment and bootstrap js . I need to fetch daterange value from the input box.
Unable to get date range in alert or console . 
Using getElementById need to fetch value of date range

```
$(function() { 
    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment(); 
    function cb(start, end) { 
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }
    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start, endDate: end, ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()], 
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')] 
        } 
    }, cb);
    cb(start, end); 
});
```

Get Date Range

```
function myFunction() { 
    var x = document.getElementById("reportrange").value;
    console.log(x); 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; 
}
```

```html
<html><!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);
    
});


</script>

<body>
<div id="reportrange"  class="pull-left" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 29%">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Get Date Range</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("reportrange").value;
    console.log(x);
 alert(x);
   
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code? Please edit and include that at the top. We aren't magic debuggers. Also format your code properly because before I edited it was a one liner. No one likes forced one liners. Always indent and add new lines after semi colons.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience , Have attached html code Basically i need to alert the selected value of date range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `myFunction` to show the following

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = $("#reportrange").text();
    console.log(x);
    alert(x);

}
```

I replaced `document.getElementById` because you are already using jQuery and should just use the jQuery function `$` and instead of `value` which is an attribute that not all DOMs have, you should call `text`. To get the values of DOMs generally you can call `text()` `html()` or `val()` but they serve different purposes. [The documentation for `text()` illustrates this](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);
    
});


</script>

<body>
<div id="reportrange"  class="pull-left" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 29%">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Get Date Range</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = $("#reportrange").text();
    console.log(x);
 alert(x);
   
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Matthew Ciaramitaro, it worked .It was basically Jquery function.Thanks